# Ubuntu server monitoring

Tags: monitoring, colocation

I'm about to begin to colocate a server and I'm looking for lightweight server monitoring.  From those of you with experience, what kind of monitoring should I look for?  What do I want to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I used monit for a long time, it's really more of a "keep things online" deal, but it has a web interface as well. I didn't ever notice it taking up too many resources, and it's really configurable. http://mmonit.com/monit/ 
Otherwise Nagios is nice, but a bit more heavy-weight.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to ensure you host is up and your various services are running.  It is also helpful to monitor that your service is accessible from outside the site. I have used Nagios, and it does the job well.  It is rather complex to setup for a single server though.

For graphing status I have used MRTG, and an rrd plugin for Nagios.  I just recently started using munin.  The advantage of munin is you can configure warnings when you go outside a boundary on something you are monitoring.  If required you can run munin over ssh.